# Automatically add images to media library

Tags: image, wordpress, function

I'm creating a wordpress theme and I have 5 images I want to distribute with it. Is it possible that when the user loads my theme, my 5 images are automatically placed in the media library?

Comment: Why would you want to add them to the media library? Why not just package them with your theme?

Answer (score 0):

Place the images in your theme folder. Then retrieve them like so:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img1.jpg" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img2.jpg" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img3.jpg" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img4.jpg" />
<img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/img5.jpg" />
```